# c# firestore add timestamp field in visual studio project

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm succesfully adding those data to firestore with my visual studio c# application using the library:

Google.Cloud.Firestore

now, I need to add a new field the timestamp but how to decleare it? I haven't find a property for it. Any suggestion?

Thanks

```
CollectionReference coll = database.Collection("reports");
            Dictionary<string, object> data1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"fileId", fileId},
                {"fileName", fileName},
                {"type", type},
                {"userId", userId},
                {"url", urlReport },
                {"plantId", plantId },
            };
            coll.AddAsync(data1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `Google.Cloud.Firestore` library, I'd expect you to be able to use [`FieldValue.ServerTimestamp`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.FieldValue#Google_Cloud_Firestore_FieldValue_ServerTimestamp):

```cs
CollectionReference coll = database.Collection("reports");
Dictionary<string, object> data1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"fileId", fileId},
    {"fileName", fileName},
    {"type", type},
    {"userId", userId},
    {"url", urlReport },
    {"plantId", plantId },
    {"timestamp", FieldValue.ServerTimestamp}
};
await coll.AddAsync(data1);
```

Note that the library supports anonymous types as well, so it would be simpler to write:

```cs
CollectionReference coll = database.Collection("reports");
var data1 = new { fileId, fileName, type, userId,
                  url = urlReport, plantId, timestamp = FieldValue.ServerTimestamp };
await coll.AddAsync(data1);
```